# Using -f string format on get-content data in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, string-formatting, onenote

I've got an XML template I put in a txt file. I'd like to import it to a variable and use "-f" to input my data into the string. Something like:

```
$XMLtmplt = get-content C:\XMLtemplate.txt
$XML = "$XMLtmplt" -f $objID $pageTitle $otherData
$OneNoteObject.UpdatePageContent($XML)
```

This works when the $XMLtmplt variable is set with a small string, but fails when I import a large string from a file. I'd rather not put a long XML string in my script; importing from a file is nice. My only work around thus far is to break up the data before and after the insertion point like:

```
$XML = "<All the first data>"
$XML += $1stVariableToInsert
$XML += "<more XML stuff>"
$XML += $2ndVariableToInsert
...
$OneNoteObject.UpdatePageContent($XML)
```

BTW, this is for building XML for the MS OneNote API, which I've found to be quite temperamental. The error codes are less than descriptive. A general "bad XML" doesn't help when you've got hundreds of lines of XML.

Any ideas?

Comment: How long is long? Could you give an example of the XML?

Answer (score 0):

One specific issue:

```
$XML = "$XMLtmplt" -f $objID $pageTitle $otherData
```

the arguments for substitution with `-f` should be comma separated: the format operator takes *two* arguments: a string to its right and an array to its left:

```
$XML = "$XMLtmplt" -f $objID, $pageTitle, $otherData
```